# Can I map (CNAME) a custom domain to a subdomain that is part of a Wildcard on Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure, web-applications, dns

I have a website on Azure Cloud Services, and I have enabled a wildcard for my website like: *.mywebsite.com

Then if a customer registers and select as his subdomain: client1.mywebsite.com, I only save the subdomain associated with my customer in the database. I don't need to do anything on the portal. This works as well on Azure Web Apps (Azure Websites).

Now, if my client goes to his domain provider and sets a DNS entry like:

www.client1.com CNAME client1.mywebsite.com

I can handle that correctly in Cloud Services without having to register "www.client1.com" in the Azure Portal. Is that possible in Azure Websites without having to add www.client1.com to the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no, it is not possible.

**Explanation.**

What you type in the address bar is the name that is presented to a web server in the HTTP request. Regardless of the underlying DNS responses. If a DNS look up of www.example.com provides an IP Address, whether a CNAME or an A record, that is where it will go and get data from. The only way to change that is with a HTTP Redirect.

In Azure the incoming server name is used to direct traffic to the correct web app (On the same set of IP Addresses there might be thousands of other websites registered) The only way it knows how to distinguish where to send the request is from the incoming server name.

**Why this worked on Cloud Services.**

Behind a cloud service was an IP Address that was unique to your servers behind it. When a cloud service got a HTTP request, it would process it, because there was nowhere else to send it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I thought that this would be the case. I'll split the part that need custom domains and add a proxy, so I can continue to use Azure Web Apps as I prefer, instead of going back to a VM for everything.